# "Jailed" user can access `/dev` directory under SFTP

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sftp, cygwin

I set up a jail for a remote user under SSH (Cygwin), and he is jailed at `/jail/user/home/user`. When he connects with some SFTP client (ex: Filezilla), he can access his `/home/user` folder and control it, but also `/dev` folder too. In this folder, he can read, write, but not delete or download files.

There's something wrong with `ChrootDirectory` directive in sshd_config file?

Comment: Did you add the command as part of a Match Group statement? If so, is your user part of the group?

Comment: I mainly add that because I just tried with my test user and totally forgot to add my "sftp" group as a supplemental group.

Comment: As an addition, I tested the following and it did not allow access to /dev.

Match Group sftp
  ChrootDirectory /home/sftp/
  AllowTCPForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp

Comment: Oh whoops, didn't see that you're using win2008. God only knows...

Comment: Yes, there's the `match` statement:
`Match Group [GROUPNAME]
    ChrootDirectory /jail/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no`
The user is member of the group and can't view another folders, except `/dev`. I changed `ChrootDirectory` to `/home/[USER]`, but doesn't work too. This setting is at bottom of sshd_config file.

The `X11Forwarding` directive can make some influence in this case?

Comment: I recently tried setting up an sftp server using cygwin and found myself spending so much time trying to get it to work that I looked at other options. There are a couple of free ones, which I tried, but ended up buying the Bitvise server. It costs about the same as 2 or so hours of your time. But I can highly recommend it as it should work out cheaper if you count your time. Everything just works and works as you would expect it to work. I have no relation with Bitvise, other than that purchase.

Comment: I should add that I saw exactly the same problem you mention and never managed to restrict it. In this case I needed a restricted sftp server as it was going to be used to exchange sensitive files with 3rd parties.